# How to compare element of list of lists and breakdown one column into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I want to divide below Columns_A and Columns_B into 3 columns.

What approach I am thinking of creating(but no idea what to write in python):

1. breakdown Columns_A and Columns_B into 3 columns
2. merge pass_one and pass_two and pass_three
3. append Columns_C and Columns_D to the longest values of list

Original data(I changed it to list of lists):

| Columns_A | Columns_B | Columns_C | Columns_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | Y |
| 1 | A | X | Y |
| 1 | A | X | Y |
| 2 | B | X | Y |
| 2 | B | X | Y |
| 3 | C | X | Y |
| 3 | C | X | Y |
| 3 | C | X | Y |
| 3 | C | X | Y |
| 11 | D | Z | Q |
| 12 | E | Z | Q |
| 12 | E | Z | Q |
| 12 | E | Z | Q |
| 13 | F | Z | Q |
| 13 | F | Z | Q |

What I would like to create:

| Columns_A_1 | Columns_B_1 | Columns_A_2 | Columns_B_2 | Columns_A_3 | Columns_B_3 | Columns_C | Columns_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 | B | 3 | C | X | Y |
| 1 | A | 2 | B | 3 | C | X | Y |
| 1 | A | Blacnk | Blacnk | 3 | C | X | Y |
| Blacnk | Blacnk | Blacnk | Blacnk | 3 | C | X | Y |
| 11 | D | 12 | E | 13 | F | Z | Q |
| Blank | Blank | 12 | E | 13 | F | Z | Q |
| Blank | Blank | 12 | E | Blank | Blank | Z | Q |

Code that I tried but didn't work (no error but pass_two & pass_two output blank):

```
#①breakdown Columns_A and Columns_B into 3 columns
!pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

dic = {'Column_A': ["1","1","1","2","2","3","3","3","3","11","12","12","12","13","13"],
    'Column_B': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F'],
    'Column_C': ['X'] * 9 + ['Z'] * 6,
    'Column_D': ['Y'] * 9 + ['Q'] * 6,}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
list_data = df.values.tolist()

pass_one = [] #Columns_A_1 and Columns_A_1 
pass_two = [] #Columns_A_2 and Columns_B_2
pass_three = [] #Columns_A_3 and Columns_B_3

for row in list_data:
    Columns_A = row[0]
    Columns_B = row[1]
    Columns_C = row[2]
    Columns_D = row[3]
    list_one = [Columns_A ,Columns_B] #I would like to append these data set
    if Columns_C in Columns_C and Columns_A not in Columns_A:
        pass_two.append(list_one)
        if Columns_C in Columns_C and Columns_A not in Columns_A:
            pass_three.append(list_one)
    else:
        pass_one.append(list_one)
```

Once Columns_A and Columns_B is separated into 3 list of lists:
I would like to merge pass_one and pass_two and pass_three

At last, append Columns_C and Columns_D to the longest values of list

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this??

Comment: what's the rule for breaking down column A into A_1 and A_2?

Comment: Hi @ignoring_gravity, 
I wanted to breakdown column A when the value changes(for example, columns A had "1" at first and next value "2" came up, so I would like to assign "1" to A_1 and "2" to A_2 )
The number "1" & "2" & "3" are random number I assigned as an example, but theu supposed to be strings. Sorry if that was confusing.
The real data I am trying to restructure is column A = question_id, column B = time_stamp, column C = section_id, column D = task_id. 
Also, column A & column B are proportional, so their value changes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but perhaps it'll get you one step further. I assumed your sort criteria was Column_A mod 10:

```
# create the column we can group by; column A integers mod 10                   
df['Column_A_sort'] = df['Column_A'].astype(int) % 10                           
                                                                                
# group by that value                                                           
df.groupby('Column_A_sort').agg(list)
```

Output:

```
for i in g.groups:
  print(g.get_group(i))
```

prints:

```
  Column_A Column_B Column_C Column_D  Column_A_sort
0        1        A        X        Y              1
1        1        A        X        Y              1
2        1        A        X        Y              1
9       11        D        Z        Q              1
   Column_A Column_B Column_C Column_D  Column_A_sort
3         2        B        X        Y              2
4         2        B        X        Y              2
10       12        E        Z        Q              2
11       12        E        Z        Q              2
12       12        E        Z        Q              2
   Column_A Column_B Column_C Column_D  Column_A_sort
5         3        C        X        Y              3
6         3        C        X        Y              3
7         3        C        X        Y              3
8         3        C        X        Y              3
13       13        F        Z        Q              3
14       13        F        Z        Q              3
```

As [ignoring_gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4451315/ignoring-gravity) suggests, in order to go further, it'd be helpful to understand exactly your criteria for sorting and recombining the columns.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I assigned column A's number randomly...Sorry for the confusing example.
The real data I am trying to restructure is column A = question_id, column B = time_stamp, column C = section_id, column D = task_id. Also, column A & column B are proportional, so their value changes at the same time. 
Is there a way to group by string value??

Comment: You can definitely use groupby with exact string values; for example, give each unique value in column A its own group. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html
Sometimes I find it useful to play around in a Python shell with a subset of my data. Maybe that'd work for you?

Comment: i didn't know groupby work for string data as well! Thank you for your advice and will try it out!!